# Powershell casting array objects and changing datatypes

Tags: arrays, csv, powershell

I have two powershell string array of arrays (from import csv) that I need to compare. 
They are as such:

```
Array 1  / File 1
"Date","Descrption","Amount"
"05/12/2016","Desc1","-40.00"
"05/15/2016","Desc2","-50.00"

Array 2  / File 2
"Date","Description","Amount"
"5/12/2016","Desc1","-40"
"5/15/2016","Desc2","-50"
```

If you look closely, the records are identical and need to match when using compare object.

So, is there a way I can cast the first object in each record to a date and the third object to a number, within that same array or arrays.

Also can I ignore any errors found while casting (empty dates or numbers).

Thank you!!

PS. Specifically looking for something like

```
 import-object file1.csv | for-each object { cast $_.Date as date, ignore errors, cast $_Amount as number, ignore errors }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to make use of **-as** operator to cast the data to an object.

```
Import-Csv 'File1.csv' | ForEach {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Date = $_.Date -as [datetime]
        Description = $_.Description
        Amount = $_.Amount -as [int]
    }
}
```

The benefit of doing this is that it won't thrown an error if it fails (but will not present the data and just be Null).

```
'06/07/2015' -as [datetime]
'Wont Work' -as [datetime]

10.00 -as [int]
'Wont Work' -as [int]
```

Comment: Ok very very close!! Just one more request - can I cast it as a decimal with exactly two digits of precision. Problem is that some records have 50.00 in them and when they repeat, the amount is 50.. compare object treats these as different when comparing decimals.. or does it? Checking.